# Why is a list inside class list erased when using list.clear()

Tags: c#, list

if `choices.Clear();` is not use here, the output will be `question_1, aaa, bbb, ccc, question_1, aaa, bbb, ccc, 111, 222, 333, question_2, aaa, bbb, ccc, 111, 222, 333`

my desired output will be `question_1, aaa, bbb, ccc, question_2, 111, 222, 333`

that is why I put `choices.Clear();` in between because I wanted to erase the previous assigned data in 'choices' list

but when i put `choices.Clear();` it deleted the whole thing whichever list that holds `choices` list

I have a code as below:

Quiz.cs

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Question
{
    public string question;
    public List<string> choice;
    public int option;
}
```

GameController.cs

```
List<Question> question_list = new List<Question>();
List<string> choices = new List<string>();

string question;

void Start()
{
    AssignData("question_1", "aaa", "bbb", "ccc");
    ViewData();

    choices.Clear(); // <- this delete ques.choice inside question_list
    
    AssignData("question_2", "111", "222", "333");
    ViewData();
}

public void AssignData(string question, string choice1, string choice2, string choice3)
{
    choices.Add(choice1);
    choices.Add(choice2);
    choices.Add(choice3);

    question = question;

    var ques = new Question();
    ques.question = question;
    ques.choice = choices;
    ques.option = 2;
    question_list.Add(ques);
}

public void ViewData()
{
    for(int i=0; i < question_list.Count; i++)
    {
        Debug.Log(question_list[i].question);
        foreach(var item in question_list[i].choice)
        {
            Debug.Log(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating new instance of `choices` when you assign it to `ques.choice` property,

```
ques.choice = new List<string>(choices);
```

---

Why do we need it?

- In your case `ques.choice=choices` is just referring `choices` instance. Any operation is done on `choices` will reflect in `ques.choice`.
- To avoid this reference, `new List<string>(choices)` will create new instance of same list.
- This will break reference chain and will avoid updating `ques.choice` after updating `choices`

[.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Mtj6Sd)

---

[From MSDN: Reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types)

> With reference types, two variables can reference the same object;
> therefore, operations on one variable can affect the object referenced
> by the other variable

Comment: oh wow that work, can you explain why we need to declare the list like that?

Comment: I added fiddle, hope fiddle and the description will help you to understand why we created new instance of `choice` list

Comment: does `ques.choice = choices.ToList()` same logic? because it works also

Comment: yeah, `ToList()` does the same think that I mentioned. Look at the documentation: [Enumerable.ToList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolist?view=net-7.0). It clearly says **Creates a List<T>** from an IEnumerable<T>.